# Python - Reading date from h5 give me a string instead of date format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Why are the following commands provide me with the following.  Why is the Date in "1396224000000000000"

```
import pandas as pd 
h5 = pd.HDFStore('./vstoxx_data_31032014.h5', 'r') 
futures_data = h5['futures_data']  # VSTOXX futures data 
options_data = h5['options_data']  # VSTOXX call option data    
h5.close()
```

The contents of futures_data is

```
    Date                EXP_YEAR EXP_MONTH PRICE MATURITY             TTM
496 1396224000000000000 2014     4         17.85 13977792000000000000 0.094

(followed by more similar rows)
```

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

```
futures_data['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(futures_data.DATE)
```

Comment: please answer the exact question and elaborate a little

Comment: These data are from Yves Hilpisch's repo accompanying his book Python for Finance (https://github.com/yhilpisch/py4fi).  I experienced the same format when I read the data as Ernest did.  Having not found an option with HDFStore to convert the dates in-line, I suggest adding two additional lines of code, as suggested in the answer.  This code yields a more recognizable date format.